# Adding NSURL to a mutable array in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a for loop,it contacts an array of strings to a part of a URL and then converts it to NSURL and pushes them one by one inside a mutablearray. The problem is that the mutableArray is null when i NSlog it outside the for loop.
Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < news_Image.count; i++) {
    concatURLS = [mediaURL stringByAppendingString:
    [news_Image objectAtIndex:i]];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:concatURLS];
    [urlArrays addObject:url];        
}
```

Comment: Post the code for creating the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you ever allocate the mutable array?

You need to make sure that you are calling:

```
 NSMutableArray * urlArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

before the for loop.

Also, make sure news_image has been allocated as well.